# How do I specify a start index for the inner loop with enumerate in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I've got the following code:

```
nums = [1, 2, 23, 1, 2, 3, ..., 10] # a lot of elements
for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
   for j, num2 in enumerate(nums):
      if (i >= j): 
          continue
      # do something
```

I believe we'll iterate over `N^2` pairs here, is there any way to start `j` from `i + 1` in the first place to reduce number of operations by a half?

Comment: You could just slice the list before giving it to `enumerate` couldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same combinations of elements by using [itertool.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). This might be a cleaner option and avoids making a slice of the list:

```
from itertools import product, combinations

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4] # a lot of elements

for num1, num2 in combinations(nums,2):
    print(num1, num2) # or do something else
```

> 1 2
>   1 3
>   1 4
>   2 3
>   2 4
>   3 4

Answer (score 0):

I can use slicing (the idea was given by @Carcigenicate):

```
nums = [1, 2, 23, 1, 2, 3, ..., 10] # a lot of elements
for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
   for j, num2 in enumerate(nums[i+1:]):
      # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice your list before passing it to enumerate:

```
nums = [1, 2, 23, 1, 2, 3, ..., 10] # a lot of elements
for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
   for j, num2 in enumerate(nums[i+1:]):
      # do something
```

If you're unfamiliar with slice, it allows you to specify a subset of the elements:

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> i = 2
>>> nums[i:]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Though I caution this wouldn't reduce the overall complexity of your algorithm too much.

Comment: Why should you have an `if` check?

Comment: thanks @Austin that bit from the original snippet is obviously unnecessary after adding the slice, so I removed it.